# Retrive friends of friends in gmail for ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, gmail, gmail-api

> I want to retrieve friends of friends of gmail account in my iPhone
>   application. I have no any idea about integration of gmail in iPhone
>   application.
>
> Which framework I need to use or how to integrate and retrieve friends
>   of friends ?

**If there is any demo or link please suggest me.**

Comment: I don't believe Gmail provides friends of friends relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ios

and follow the steps to integrate gmail in your application.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this example http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/accessing-google-services-using-the-oauth-20-protocol--mobile-18394 i think guide for this app :-)

After, you can use the api links.

Comment: I am not getting the framework, can you send me the link ?

Comment: get the GoogleOAuth.m and GoogleOAuth.h files from the example project. Thats it.

Comment: I want to use gmail-api for my iphone app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24452747/3870428

Comment: In demo project I can see only my basic detail like name, gender, locale, etc., what should I do if I want to retrive detail of my friends and friends of friends ?